# Change colour navbar header Ionic 2

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I have this problem... My colour is white right now, my code is like this:

```
<ion-header >
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      HELLO
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Change color with this opcion is easy (primary, secondary, danger, light, dark)

```
<ion-header >
      <ion-navbar danger>
        <ion-title>
          HELLO
        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>
```

but my problem is when I want to use custom colors. 
Somebody know how can I resolve it?
Thanks inadvance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There're two ways of doing this, based on if you want to change the color only in a single page, or if you want to change it in all the pages from your app:

#### 1) Change it in a single page/view

Just like you can see [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/)

> To change the theme, just tweak the `$colors` map in your
>   `src/theme/variables.scss` file:

```
$colors: (
  // ...
  newcolor:    #55acee

)
```

And then use it in the view

```
 <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar color="newcolor">
        <ion-title>
          HELLO
        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>
```

#### 2) Change it in all the pages/views

In this case, you'd need to add the following in your `variables.scss` file to override Ionic's defaults:

```
$toolbar-ios-background: #55acee;
$toolbar-md-background: #55acee;
$toolbar-wp-background: #55acee;
```

---

#### Edit

> Hi, how can I add gradient in app/theme/app.variables.scss?

You could add the colors that you're going to use in the `src/theme/variables.scss`:

```
$header-first-color: #AAAAAA;
$header-last-color: #000000;
```

And then set a rule to use it (in your `app.scss` file if you want to apply it to every page, or in the `page-name.scss` file if you want to apply it to a single page):

```
ion-header {
    .toolbar-background {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, $header-first-color 0%, $header-last-color 100%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hmm.. for me it doesn't update when I do newcolor in the ion-navbar. I also cleared my cache.

Comment: @JohnAndrews try with `<ion-navbar color="newcolor">` since the answer was related to a previous version of Ionic

Comment: Hi , how can  i add gradient in  app/theme/app.variables.scss?

Answer (score 4):

Might be better to overwrite the ionic variable in your `variables.scss` file

So you can create a custom color variable

```
 $new-color:#55acee;
```

and then pass it into the ionic variable

```
$toolbar-ios-background:($new-color);
$toolbar-md-background($new-color);
$toolbar-wp-background($new-color);
```

you can find all the ionic variables [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)